# How do i use a part of HTML template in my various other templates using django templates language?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have a template named 'popup.html' and I have to use this part of code (ie) the html in to my other templates whenever needed. I tried using {% extends 'popup.html' %} whenever needed but it throws me error

PS. I already use {% extends 'layout.html' %} for my navbar inheritance in all pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `{% include 'template.html' %}` tag is what your are looking for.

You can look it up here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/builtins/#include